# Speed of printf()

Tags: c, speed-test

I was having some fun in **C** language with **time.h** library, trying to measure the number of clock ticks of some basic functions, just to figure out how fast they actually are.
I used the [clock() function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/).
In this case I was measuring the **printf()** function.

Look at my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void main()
{
    const int LIMIT = 2000;
    const int LOOP = 20;
    int results[LOOP];

    for(int i=0; i<LOOP; i++)
    {
        int j;
        clock_t time01 = clock();

        for(j=1; j<LIMIT; j++)
        {
            printf("a");
        }

        clock_t time02 = clock();
        results[i] = (int) (time02 - time01);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<LOOP; i++)
    {
        printf("\nCLOCK TIME: %d.", results[i]);        
    }
    getchar();
}
```

The program just basically counts 20 times the number of clock ticks of 2000 times called printf("a") function.

**The strange thing I don't understand is the result.** I get most of the time, even when doing other tests, randomly **two groups** of results:

```
CLOCK TIME: 31.
CLOCK TIME: 47.
CLOCK TIME: 47.
CLOCK TIME: 31.
CLOCK TIME: 47.
CLOCK TIME: 31.
CLOCK TIME: 47.
CLOCK TIME: 31.
CLOCK TIME: 47.
CLOCK TIME: 47.
CLOCK TIME: 31.
CLOCK TIME: 47.
CLOCK TIME: 31.
CLOCK TIME: 47.
CLOCK TIME: 47.
CLOCK TIME: 31.
CLOCK TIME: 47.
CLOCK TIME: 31.
CLOCK TIME: 47.
CLOCK TIME: 31.
```

I don't understand how exactly compiler handles that function. There is some test for **%** character I guess, but that wouldn't make that difference. Looks more like compiler is doing something in the memory... (?) Does anyone know the precise background of compiling this code or why there appears that difference mentioned above? Or at least some link that would help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Most of the time is spend doing I/O and printing. The cost of the actual parsing of the format string (and most of the rest of your program) is minimal compared to that I/O time.

Comment: OS scheduling, waiting for I/O...

Comment: You have to remember, you are at the mercy of the OS here, namely the scheduler and the I/O subsystem. Those times seem to indicate whether it took 2 or 3 scheduler quanta.

Comment: The typical clock resolution is 10ms. Check with `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to see if the difference you see is essentially one clock tick. Also, you shouldn't measure `printf`, but rather `sprintf` or something like that which doesn't depend on the speed of your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of at least two possible causes:

1. Your clock has limited resolution.
2. `printf` will occasionally be flushing its buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers (in particular recent versions of `gcc` on recent Linux distributions, when optimizing with `-O2`) are able to optimize `printf("a")` into code very similar to `putchar(`a`)`

But most of the time is spent in the kernel doing the `write` system call.

Comment: Well the write sys call always causes a context switch, so at that point your process is waiting to be scheduled again.

Comment: Well, magic has to be hidden somewhere inside the PC, because when trying to do this test with empty string and **puts("");**, it takes literally no time. But **printf("");** really takes some time to do its _nothing_..

Answer (score -1):

man page of `clock` said that it returns an

> ***approximation** of processor time used by the program*

This approxmation is based on the famous [Time Stamp Counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter). As wikipedia says :

> It counts the number of cycles since reset

Sadly, nowadays, this counter can vary between core.

> There is no promise that the timestamp counters of multiple CPUs on a single motherboard will be synchronized.

So beware to lock your code on a certain cpu, otherwise, you will continue to have strange results. And since you seems to search precise results, you can use this code instead of `clock` call :

```
  uint64_t rdtsc(void) {
    uint32_t lo, hi;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (      // serialize
    "xorl %%eax,%%eax \n        cpuid"
    ::: "%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
    /* We cannot use "=A", since this would use %rax on x86_64 and return only the lower 32bits of the TSC */
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a" (lo), "=d" (hi));
    return (uint64_t)hi << 32 | lo;
  }
```

Comment: There is no requirement that clock(3) has to use the TSC. It also does not count cycles, but clocks, which is an implementation-dependent value, which happens to be 1 µs in POSIX.